# A simple aws lambda post request is returning internal server error while I am trying to invoke it from Postman

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to put up a simple AWS lambda POST request. But when I am trying to hit the API from postman it is returning "Internal Server Error Message".

I have already tried to tweak the serverless.yml file but nothing seems to work till now. Every time it is returning the same message. I tested the lambda from AWS console and it's giving the correct response there.

Following is the serverless.yml

```
service: execute-api

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.6

  stage: devfour
  region: ap-south-1

functions:
  taxorunner:
    handler: taxonomy.taxorunner
    events:
      - http:
          path: uploadForm
          method: post
          cors: true
```

Python code:

```py
def taxorunner(event, context):
    return {"status": "OK"}
```

The API call should return

```
{"status": "OK"}
```

But it is returning:

```
{
    "message": "Internal server error"
}
```

[Edit]: So I found out the answer. The response object should have its proper keys, not just any field. So changed the response object to:

```py
response = {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": json.dumps({
            "id" : 1
        })
    }
```